# Google Places API - Place Picker not waiting for place pick

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am trying to incorporate Google Places API into my application.

I have done the preliminary things but for some reason when I start the activity via

`startActivityForResult(Intent, Int);`

The application will briefly pop up the place picker intent but will close before the user has the opportunity to select a location and returns a 'Not OK' Activity.Result.

Here is the code to set up the activity along with almost the exact same thing launching a contact select intent and working fine,

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
        .Builder(this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

Intent intent = getIntent();
getIntentData(intent);

/*Contact Select, works fine*/
int resulter = 3;
Intent intenter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contact"));
intenter.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intenter, resulter);

try {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and here is the callback, this returns the correct information for the contact select (request code = 3) but incorrect information for the Place Picker (request code = 2 [this part is correct, but the result code is incorrect]),

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "wwhhhahahahahahahahahaah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hytexsoftware.dummy" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_load_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayLocations"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_locations" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".util.ShowLocationOnMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_location_on_map" >
        </activity>

    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Show your manifest file, the problem is likely there.

Comment: You'll need to follow the signup and API key instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) and add an API key to your AndroidManifest.

Comment: I have added the API key, see freshly added manifest contents. Or at least I believe I have done this correctly. I followed that exact tutorial to do so.

Comment: Ah it looks like the instructions there are a bit confusing - your manifest should look like this:

  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="API_KEY_GOES_HERE"/>

You only want to put your API key in the API_KEY_GOES_HERE section.  I'll file a bug internally to update those instructions - sorry for the trouble!    

Also you should probably remove that key from your original post so others can't use it :)

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Developer Console and enable Google Places API for Android for your project